# Human or Natural sort for digits in the middle of string?

Tags: sorting

I know natural sorting (or human sorting?) is quite good on sorting a sequence of strings with digits. And recently, I applied it on generated (rendered) image sequences. The result looks like the following:

- ooxx_1.jpg
- ooxx_2.jpg
- ...
- ooxx_11.jpg
- ...

What if there are suffix characters after the digits? The sorting result would be like this:

- ooxx_1.jpg
- ooxx_1_depth.jpg
- ooxx_2.jpg
- ooxx_2_depth.jpg
- ...

While I am looking for the following sorted result:

- ooxx_1.jpg
- ooxx_2.jpg
- ...
- ooxx_1_depth.jpg
- ooxx_2_depth.jpg
- ...

Any idea?

Comment: To get that all you need to do is split the letter and number parts and then sort by parts with the letters first and then the numbers. This is a simple variation of the natural sort.

Comment: I think it should be sorted by digits first then letters by making use of stable sort?!